# CodeIgniter Campaign Best Practice

Tags: php, codeigniter

I’ve got what I think is a simple problem but I’m having a tough time working out what the best strategy is and I hoping you could help.

I’m using CodeIgniter to build my new website (currently in dev), where users are able to create, edit and delete campaigns. And each campaign has a sub-campaign which the can also edit, delete and create each sub-campaign.

Whilst in the add campaign view, how do I (in pseudo code) mark the form (or session in a way where the sub campaign the user is creating gets assigned to the correct campaign. My thoughts at the moment are to either

(1) Use the id of the campaign within the url and pull the correct segment. For example                                                                                             http://www.website.com/campaign/**12345**/add-sub-campaign

or

(2) Inside the form element put the name of the campaign in a hidden input field, and grab that through the post and use that to link the new sub-campaign to the campaign.

Thanks for your help with this tedious question! I’d prefer just to do it the right way first time.

Comment: Both would work fine. But, when debugging, it is handy to see a db identifier in a page address string, and it can also be used by analytics software to see which campaigns are being viewed/edited most often. So I would go with the first one, in general.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a URL schema like `example.com/campaigns/add/234`

Here 234 is the parent campaign ID

In your `Campaign` controller

```
public function add($parent_id = ''){ //......}
```

This saves you from using hidden field in the form as well

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use a hidden form input e.g. id of campaign you are assigning under.

If you use url segments, it can create such problems in a way that id of segment is changed by user and campaign is assigned to totally different one. (User changes `website.com/campaign/12345/add-sub-campaign` into `website.com/campaign/54321/add-sub-campaign`) Plus, url segmentation could make you check more about what user doing. Is id from url segment valid or not etc.

Comment: And what would hold someone from changing the hidden input's value? Either way you should check if the user is allowed to create campaigns  with that parent. Never trust the user.